# How to access sharepoint lists present in a sharepoint site which resides in cloude

Tags: sharepoint, cloud

My requirement is as follows:

There is a sharepoint site in cloud and this site has sharepoint lists into which data has to be populated from sql DB which is present on-premise.

As the DB is on-premise and is has to interact with sharepoint which is in cloud. How can I access or get the sharepoint lists present in the site and update the content ??

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like what you want to use is the lists.asmx web service, which is explained here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774654(v=office.12).aspx

What you do **not** want to do is modify the SQL DB directly. Down that path lies nothing but trouble.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the response. If sharepoint and sql DB are in same network, I can get sharepoint lists using lists.asmx and update the lists with Content present in DB. My requirement here is, Sharepoint is in Cloud and SQL DB is in corp network, Now I have to access the sharepoint lists ( which is in cloud) from corp network

Comment: If you're wanting to access that from a completely different network, I think the way to do it is still via the lists.asmx; however, you're going to need to set up some form of authentication to allow everything to speak to each other. I think that rules Kerberos right out, which is unfortunate, as Kerberos is the easiest way of setting this up (wow, did I just type that?).